# Get complete path from visitor

Tags: php

My code

```
$site = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Is just loggin

```
index.php
```

and not the complete path e.g. `www.url.index.php/folder/doc.php`

Why? Is this command wrong?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_SERVER)` to see what all of your options really are

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

You'll see what's actually available. You probably want to look at $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] too.

Answer (score 0):

to get complete path from user use  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, to get full path as follow.

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` just shows the file path [relative to the document root](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
.

you will need a combination such as:

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

this will give you both the domain name, e.g. `www.example.com`, plus the file name and path, e.g. `/users/login.php`, concatenated into one string.